# Bootstrap css drop-down menu not rendering properly in IE9. What can be the issue?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, background-color

In one of my project, a bootstrap powered dark theme, drop-down menu in subnav isn't rendering properly in IE9. It works fine in firefox, chrome, opera and safari. I tried to debug it but wasn't able to find the problem. What may be the problem? Here are two screenshots depicting the problem -

1) In Firefox it works fine.

[image: In Firefox it works fine.]

2) But in IE9 it appears as transparent, i.e., it is not rendering background color.

[image: Doesn't render properly in IE9]

I have uploaded it on my server. You can check it live here - http://anujkumar.com/templates/dsadmin/

Comment: This may not be the problem, but you should fix your search form - you have it as a direct child of a `<ul>`.  Other than that, it seems like the issue is something to do with the menu bar being `position:fixed;` - the dropdown appears to be rendering behind the body, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks for bringing the search form issue to my notice. I will update it. 

Regarding the main issue, I believe it is not rendering behind body as its border and box-shadow are visible. It's background that isn't rendering for some unknown reasons. Also, none of the menu items are actually clickable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A place to begin your investigation of the problem may be the Microsoft [Gradient Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your subnav.css file.

When you remove the following MS Filter property, the drop-down displays in IE 9:

```
.subnav {
      ...
     progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1f1f1f', endColorstr='#1f1f1f', GradientType=0); 
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Also Bootstrap has an `.reset-filter()` less mixin for it:

```
// Reset filters for IE
.reset-filter() {
  filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false)"));
}
```

It fixed exactly the same problem for me (**Bootstrap ver.2.0.4**)